# Neural network weight initialization?

Tags: neural-networks, batch-normalization

I'm trying to understand neural network weight initialization but i need help to decipher the language people use to describe fan-in.

"N (where n is the number of the neurons inputs)"... or this definition... fan-in (the number of connections feeding into the node)", however in the Xavier Glorot paper http://machinelearning.wustl.edu/mlpapers/paper_files/AISTATS2010_GlorotB10.pdf "n is the size of the previous layer (the number
of columns of W)" which sounds to me like biases are excluded.

So, does "N" aka? "fan-in" include bias connections or not.

For example, consider a neuron whose inputs are two other neurons and a bias node from the previous layer. Is the fan-in two or three?

Comment: Bias will not have any weights associated with it. A neuron can never output a bias. Bias is learned just like the weights to a neuron-to-neuron connection.

Comment: "Bias will not have any weights associated with it" Hmm... I think of bias's like shown here: http://natekohl.net/media/bias-net.gif basically a "1" input where the weight is what learns. I get that in code implementation it's a "bias" column vector added to the weights * previous-layer outputs, so is that why you say a bias has no weight? I think you can see from that picture though why i think of biases as a always-on neuron (that has no inputs of its own), and start wondering if fan-in count includes them when performing weight initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**: Biases are not included. So, N / `fan_in` will be 2 in your case.

*Explanation*: Note that Glorot and Bengio 2010 base their initializations on the variances of the weights. They assume $\mathbb V[z^i] \approx \mathbb V[x] \prod_{i'=0}^{i-1} n_{i'}\mathbb V[W^{i'}]$. This derivation comes from the approximating assumption that $z^i = f(s^i) \approx s^i = z^{i-1}W^i+b^i $ [which is true for certain symmetric activation functions around the 0, like the $\tanh$]. Since they assume that the variances of each element in the weight matrix are the same, and likewise for the inputs, we get:

$$\mathbb V[z^1]=\mathbb V[f(s^1)]=\mathbb V[f(xW^1+b^1)]\approx \mathbb V[xW^1+b^1] = \mathbb V[xW^1]
$$
The last equality holds because adding constant to a random variable doesn't change the variance (we're setting $b$ to 0, so it's a constant). Since all elements in the vector and matrix have the same variances [denoted $\mathbb V[x], \mathbb V[W]$ respectively], for each activation unit of the 1st layer, the variance will be equal to $=\mathbb V[x] n_0 \mathbb V[W]$, where $n_0$ is just the dimensionality of $x$ **without** the bias.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.